# IS there any differences between ANY and SOME in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql

Searching that thing in several hours, but I just found 'they do same things'. If they have same function, why developer separate in two? There are some event make they get same function during updating MYSQL..? Or Do they have any little differences ...?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow - typically you will want to attempt to write some code after researching it online or doing tutorials.  Once you have done this post you code / errors here for support.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thanks for your kindness! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/any-in-some-subqueries.html):

> The word SOME is an alias for ANY. Thus, these two statements are the
>   same:
>
> ```
> SELECT s1 FROM t1 WHERE s1 <> ANY  (SELECT s1 FROM t2);
> SELECT s1 FROM t1 WHERE s1 <> SOME (SELECT s1 FROM t2);
> ```
>
> Use of the word SOME is rare, but this example shows why it might be
>   useful. To most people, the English phrase “a is not equal to any b”
>   means “there is no b which is equal to a,” but that is not what is
>   meant by the SQL syntax. The syntax means “there is some b to which a
>   is not equal.” Using <> SOME instead helps ensure that everyone
>   understands the true meaning of the query.

Comment: oh I miss for searching that TT Thanks for your kindness!